# Landscape Orientation in android 3.1

Tags: android, android-orientation

App works fine in android 3.2 but not in android 3.1

My application is in landscape mode and I have manifest saying

```
 <activity
             android:name=".GameActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="landscape"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
       >
```

and have override the onConfigchanges where i setting it in Landscape Mode.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    }
```

Now the issue is When i run my application in 3.1 there is some wierd problem happening.
When I press home screen ..make it in potrait mode and again come back my app starts activity but shows half screen of my current activity and other activity which isingleTop.

Half screen of my current activity and on top of that old activity

It is weird I do not know why this is happening

Comment: Try to remove the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`  run it and check.

Comment: @SpK : But i do not want to restart the activity .. I want it to be in landscape without restarting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, documentation about [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) about value `screenSize`.

> The current available screen size has changed. This represents a
>   change in the currently available size, relative to the current aspect
>   ratio, so will change when the user switches between landscape and
>   portrait. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower,
>   then your activity always handles this configuration change itself
>   (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when
>   running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

So on android 3.2 setting: `android:configChanges="orientation"` is effectively ignored since screenSize is leading to recreation of activity. On android 3.1 you prevent recreation of Activity when orientation changes.
So remove `orientation` value and it should be Ok, apparently automatic recreation of activity is good for you. Or add `screenSize` value and be happy that same bug is present in both versions.

This is kind of funny bug of android that switching between activities with different orientation leads to configuration change of activity which has fixed orientation.